# PHP: socket_write hangs when client disconnects while writing

Tags: php, apache

While I'm receiving data in my iOS app (some data is received, but not all) I purposely quit the app and `socket_write` hangs on the server. Here is the relevant code:

```
error_log("start write");
$sent = socket_write($client, $string, $length);
error_log("end write");
```

I get the `"start write"` message in my error log, but that's it, it just continues to hang until I restart the php program.

I tried setting a timeout, but then I tried to upload a large file and it looks like it timed out before the upload completed. I thought a timeout was for a period of inactivity, not the total time the client is connected for. Anyways any help is appreciated. I assumed the `socket_write` would return if the socket disconnected, but either I'm wrong or the code is. Thanks for any help.

**EDIT**

Basically, I need to know when the client has disconnected. It looks like fwrite, socket_send, and socket_write all hang when the client disconnects mid-write and blocking mode is on. If I set blocking mode off, my code looks like this:

```
function send_data($client, $string)
{
    $length = strlen($string);
    socket_set_nonblock($client);
    while(true)
    {
        $sent = socket_write($client, $string, $length);
        //OR - $sent = socket_send($client, $string, $length, 0);

        if($sent === FALSE)
        {
            error_log("false");
            return;
        }
        if($sent < $length)
        {
                $string = substr($string, $sent);
                $length -= $sent;
        }
        else
            return;  
    }
}
```

The problem with this is that, `$sent === FALSE` when the client disconnects, but also when they are temporarily unavailable, which proved to happen after sending the first few bytes, thus not sending the whole string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [`socket_select()`](http://php.net/socket_select) to determine whether the socket is ready for writing; in this manner you only need to write something when the other side is ready to receive.

You still need to check how many bytes were transferred and reduce the message accordingly.

For example:

```
function send_data($client, $string)
{
    socket_set_nonblock($client);

    while ($string != '') {
        $write = [$client]; $read = $except = null;
        // set timeout to 1s
        $n = socket_select($read, $write, $except, 1);
        if ($n === false) {
            return;
        } elseif ($n > 0) {
            $length = strlen($string);
            $sent = socket_write($client, $string, $length);
            if ($sent === false || $sent == $length) {
                return;
            } else /* $sent < $length */ {
                $string = substr($string, $sent);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem with using a `null` timeout with `socket_select` is that it blocks indefinitely if the client disconnects. I also tried a timeout of 0 seconds, but if the client disconnects, `$n` is zero. I can't do `return;` if `$n` is zero because it's also zero when they're temporarily unavailable. This has been a pain, but ultimately, I used `socket_select` with a timeout of 3 seconds and everything seems good now.

Comment: @user3529796 Fair enough, didn't test my code; I've also noticed that I had swapped `$read` and `$write`, fixed that and added a timeout of 1 second instead of no timeout.

Comment: I think I had to add `if($n == 0) return;` and that's pretty much what I used. Appreciate the help.

Comment: @user3529796 The `$n == 0` condition just means the timeout was hit before the socket became ready; if that's the desired behaviour, then fine :)

Answer (score 2):

> The problem with this is that, $sent === FALSE when the client disconnects, but also when they are temporarily unavailable, which proved to happen after sending the first few bytes, thus not sending the whole string.

You need to check `socket_last_error()` for `EAGAIN`/`EWOULDBLOCK`.

It should be either error number 11 or 35, and means the socket is still connected.

**EDIT:** PHP includes [constants](http://php.net/manual/en/sockets.constants.php) for socket errors.

Test for `SOCKET_EWOULDBLOCK`. It will work on both Linux & Windows.

> socket_write definitely does not return after a client disconnect
>   (according to the error log, "start write" shows up, but not "end
>   write" even after waiting for 10 - 30 mins.

If the other end just disappears without explicitly closing the connection, that could cause an indefinite hang in a blocking `socket_write` call.

TCP will not time out automatically for a good long time. You can enforce your own timeout by using non-blocking sockets & measuring the time since the last successful write.

Alternatively, you can use the `SO_SNDTIMEO` socket option.

Comment: After trying many things, I found that `socket_last_error()` is 11 when the client is temporarily unavailable AND when they have disconnected. I ended up using a timeout since it seems to be the only solution.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is to use `socket_select` with a timeout of 3 seconds. I think as far as a computer is concerned, "temporarily unavailable" and "disconnected" are synonymous.

Comment: If my answer is what fixed your problem, it would be more useful to accept that instead of writing another answer that provides far less detail.

Comment: Often, less is more. I just wrote this since a simple timeout is the actual solution. The first answer mentioned a timeout, but gave no code; your answer used `socket_select` which is a means to provide a timeout, but there wasn't one originally. whatever. thanks to everyone!